# sdl ttf printing from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, sdl, truetype

When I trying printf with sdl from a linked list (from the first linked structure), the program stopped down.

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct ranklist {
    int point;
    char* name;
    struct ranklist *next;
} ranklist;
```

This function read from a file (result.txt)

```
ranklist* rank_read (ranklist *r, ranklist *first){

    FILE *fp = fopen("result.txt","r");
    int name_length;
    ranklist  *curr;
    int point;


    while(1==fscanf(fp, "%d", &point)){
        r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
        r->next = NULL;
        r->point = point;
        name_length = how_many_letter(fp);
        r->name = malloc(name_length + 1);
        fscanf(fp, "%s", r->name);

        if(first == NULL)
            first = curr = r;
        else
            curr = curr->next = r;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return first;
}
```

This is the sdl printing function:

```
void sdl_printing (SDL_Surface *screen, char arr[], TTF_Font *font, int x, int y){

SDL_Color white = {255, 255, 255};
SDL_Rect where = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
SDL_Surface *subtitle;

subtitle = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, arr, white);
    where.x = x;
    where.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(subtitle, NULL, screen, &where);
    SDL_FreeSurface(subtitle);
}
```

And I trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
sdl_printing (screen, first->name , font, 100, 200); //the last two is x and y
```

and then (if it works) a step to another structure in linked list:

```
first = first->next;
```

I don't have any idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` destination rectangle has zero width and zero height (the 3rd and 4th component). You need to set a width and height to see anything. Currently you're blitting into a completely flat rectangle.

Try this to see if it works:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(subtitle, NULL, screen, NULL);
```

Comment: SDL_BlitSurface() does not do software scaling and so does not use the width and height of the destination rect.  SDL_RenderCopy() does, though.

Comment: @JonnyD Yeah, you're right actually. To the OP: check if you can print a simple string like "test", perhaps you haven't initialized SDL or the surface correctly.